# Can you use Roslyn compiler from a regular .net application?

Tags: .net, roslyn

I am currently using the old CSharp Compiler (Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider) and would like to upgrade my app to use the Roslyn Compiler to take advantage of all the new language features.

Looking at the Nuget Packages, it appears that to compile code at run-time in my application using the Roslyn Compiler, it needs to be a .NET Standard Library?

I've seen plenty of examples of how to use the Roslyn Compiler at run-time, however, all the packages they mention won't install in a .NET 4.5.2 project.

Comment: Use the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) nuget package.  It is deprecated and they promised they'll delete it some day so be sure to make a copy and check it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must target at least .NET 4.6.1 to consume .NET Standard packages. See the documentation on .NET Standard compatibility [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)